# Double registration when using select into

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, audit, select-into

SQL Server 2019 CU15, Database Audit:

When auditing a `SELECT` on a database, everything looks fine,
but if I `SELECT INTO` a `#myTempDB`, I get double registration in the `AUDIT LOG`.

I created a test database for this purpose, and configured database auditing to monitor `SELECT` on my test database.

```
USE [master]

GO
Drop database if exists [AuditTestDatabase];
Create Database [AuditTestDatabase];
Use [AuditTestDatabase]
go
Create Table AuditAuditTest (N integer)
insert into AuditAuditTest (N) Values(1)
Select * From AuditAuditTest

 Create Audit output specification (server audit)
(Create the Audit in your Temp)

Use [master]
If exists (SELECT 1 FROM sys.server_audits where name='AuditFiles')
Begin
  ALTER SERVER AUDIT [AuditFiles] WITH (STATE = OFF);
  DROP SERVER AUDIT [AuditFiles];
End
Go
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [AuditFiles]
TO FILE 
(           FILEPATH = N'C:\Temp\Audit\'
            ,MAXSIZE = 10 MB
        ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647
        ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
) WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 1000, ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE, AUDIT_GUID = 'b630ef61-59c4-4318-83db-eee587c89fbe')
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [AuditFiles] WITH (STATE = ON)
GO

Create Database Audit
USE [AuditTestDatabase]
GO
If exists (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_audit_specifications where name='DatabaseAuditSpecification')
Begin
  ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DatabaseAuditSpecification] WITH (STATE = OFF);
  DROP DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DatabaseAuditSpecification];
End
Go
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DatabaseAuditSpecification]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [AuditFiles]
ADD (SELECT ON DATABASE::[AuditTestDatabase] BY [public])
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

Auditing is now running.

This can be verified by opening the Audit folder, where there should be one, and only one, sqlaudit file.

[image]

**Viewing Audit Logs from SSMS**

[image]

At this point, it only has information that auditing has started.

Next, I try this

```
Select * From [AuditTestDatabase].dbo.AuditAuditTest
```

As expected, the `SELECT` is now in the audit log

Next, I try

```
Select * Into #L From [AuditTestDatabase].dbo.AuditAuditTest
Drop Table #L
```

And take another look at Audit log.

The `SELECT` is now present 3 times, this happens every time I select into a temp table.

Is this a bug, or is there something I don’t see?